# SQL server date error

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2000, spelling

```
UPDATE tblCampaigns SET startDate = '4 December, 2010', endDate = '14 January, 2011' WHERE ID = 147
UPDATE tblCampaigns SET startDate = '24 December, 2010', endDate = '17 Febuary, 2011' WHERE parentID = 147 and campaignName = 'regerg'

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e07' 

Syntax error converting datetime from character string. 

/bb/campaignManager/index.asp, line 147
```

These work when the dates are 2010 but as soon as a 2011 is put in there it goes wrong, any ideas?  It's probably in the wrong format right?

Comment: Just spelling mistake. Now find out yourself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "February", not "Febuary"

Comment: @Tom Gullen: no problem, we all have our moments... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't ever do that: if the default date format in your database changes, then you're scuppered. Instead, always cast strings to dates explicitly, so you retain control:

```
UPDATE tblCampaigns SET startDate = convert(datetime, '20101204', 112)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=SQL.80).aspx

Comment: I am in the habit of inserting dates my way, because they can't be interpreted any other way, writing a script on a UK server which runs on a US database causes a major headache when days/months get interpreted differently.  Is this bad practise?

Comment: That's what I mean: if you tell the database that '20101204' has to be interpreted as 'yyyymmdd' (the meaning of style 112), then the database has no other choice. If you ever, for example, ended up having to run your scripts on, say, a German server, then "December" would cause an error as the server will expect "Dezember".

Comment: With German System I only get headache that they dont know about yyyy-mm-dd, but as far as I know all versions of sqlserver understand yyyymmdd without futrther settings. That means there is no need ever to use convert(datetime, '20101204', 112)
 instead of '20101204'.

Comment: Well, it's the difference between trusting the server to convert your string properly, and actually passing a date. But you're right, the ISO format of yyyymmdd usually works fine.

Comment: 'yyyymmdd' always works, as does 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss' (FWIW, the latter most resembles ISO 8601).